# Running a Flask application at a URL that is not the domain root

Tags: python, nginx, flask, gunicorn, wsgi

I am moving a Flask application from a apache2 and mod_wsgi environment to Nginx, and am having problems getting the urls to work correctly.

I want the root page of my app to appear at, for example, `http://example.org/myapp/`

My @app.route decorators are e.g. `@app.route('/')` for the root of my app (`http://example.org/myapp`) and `@app.route('/subpage')` for subpages like `http://example.org/myapp/subpage`.

Under apache this all "just worked" and my calls to `url_for()` produced URLS that got the job done.

Now my URLs from `url_for()` are in the form: `href="/subpage"`, which is sending me to the domain root, `http://example.org/subpage` instead of what I wanted: `href="./subpage"`, which would bring me to `http://example.org/myapp/subpage`.

For what it's worth, the relevant section from my Nginx config is:

```
    location /myapp/ {
        proxy_redirect     off;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:8001/;
    }
```

I am serving the application with gunicorn.

With the situation as it stands, visiting `http://example.org/myapp/` brings me to the root page of my Flask application, but all other URLs bring me back to the domain level: `http://example.org/subpage`.

I have tried setting APPLICATION_ROOT to "/myapp", but it seems to have no effect. What am I doing (horribly) wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Despite `url_for` mentioning `APPLICATION_ROOT`, that's only used if there is no current request context (i.e. not in a web server), so no use at all most of the time.

The actual mechanism is via the wsgi variable `SCRIPT_NAME`. With `gunicorn` you can pass it on the command line a couple of ways:

```
gunicorn --env SCRIPT_NAME=/myapp app:app

SCRIPT_NAME=/myapp gunicorn app:app
```

In some wsgi systems (e.g. `mod_wsgi`) it can also be passed as a request header.

For this to work, you need to **not** strip the path at the reverse proxy. The nginx config should be:

```
location /myapp {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/myapp/;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_redirect off;
}
```

or `http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock/myapp/` or wherever the upstream sever is.

Answer (score 3):

In your nginx config you should proxy pass with a HOST header that includes the subpath that your app lies at:

```
location /myapp {
    ...
    proxy_set_header   Host $host/myapp;
    ...
}
```

Then in Flask you have two options

**Option A**

Use a new `url_for` that actually prepends the HOST header to the url. This will take a path like `/mypage` and turn it into `/myapp/mypage`

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from flask import request, url_for as _url_for

def url_with_host(path):
    return '/'.join((urlparse(request.host_url).path.rstrip('/'), path.lstrip('/')))


def url_for(*args, **kwargs):
    if kwargs.get('_external') is True:
        return _url_for(*args, **kwargs)
    else:
        return url_with_host(_url_for(*args, **kwargs))
```

You can even then update the Jinja `url_for` using:

```
app.jinja_env.globals['url_for'] = url_for
```

**Option B**

Use the `_external` flag in `url_for`. This will render the links with a full path like: `http://www.example.com/myapp/mypage`

So in your flask app generate url's using

```
url_for('index', _external=True)
```

Comment: These are both really nasty workarounds that ignore the actual standard way to do it

Comment: A `Host` header that contains a path is invalid, for example.